# Keeping Vertical Menus Constant in a Webpage

Tags: html, css

I have created a webpage in which I have vertical and horizontal menus. What I need is to keep the vertical menus constant in the webpage.

I should display the data in the vertical menu corresponding to the horizontal menus. Is this possible to do with HTML alone?

I would appreciate any help.

[Visit my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KyRus/20/)

Comment: you mean depending upon the selection of horiz. menu the vertical menu items change?

Comment: ya but whether it is possible to do so with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think css property position:absolute should do what you need :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use Style in your div containers.

```
<div style="position:absolute left:100px top:150px;">
MENU ITEMS
</div>
```

OR CSS

```
menu
{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:150px;
}
```

For more go to. Try static 2. depends if u want the page to move with it or not when u scroll.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp